# WCF Service for adding Sharepoint users?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

Currently we have an application that is written in .NET 3.5, which we are planning on upgrading to .NET 4.0.

Is it possible to create a WCF service that could make use of SharePoint 2010 API to create Sharepoint users by calling that service from .NET 4.0 application? What sort of issues do you think i may run in to if we upgrade, as Sharepoint 2010 works with .NET 3.5 and not 4.0?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use .Net 3.5 web service in your .Net 4 application .
You will have difficulties with DTO types, but if you use the properly serialized xml data then, should be no problem.